# Largest effect being ignored. Is this acceptable?

Tags: inference, methodology

I am doing some statistical analysis for researchers who want to publish the results as a paper. I have done a logistic regression to predict an outcome given various demographic variables, and found which variables were significant, etc. Standard stuff.

As it turns out, one variable is twice (or more) as indicative as all the others, however it turns out it is politically unpalatable to include this variable in the final analysis, and they don't want to even control for it in assessing the other variable's impact.

I feel like this is sweeping the largest effect under the carpet, and I'm not sure I want to be included in the final publication after having the results twisted in this way.

Is this kind of thing ever justified? What should I do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "twice ... as indicative"?

Comment: The presence or absence of this binary variable changes the likelihood of the outcome by a factor of 5, whereas the other variables that we 'want' to look at change the likelihood of the outcome by at most a factor of 2.

Comment: This would be good information to include in the text of your question.

Comment: Depends a bit what you mean by "politically". Variables should be included based on theory. If their theory says the variable is not relevant, then it should be excluded.

Comment: If you feel the conclusion that they draw is valid then I don't see a problem even if the most important variable is left out.

Comment: We cannot really say for sure without more information, but to change the analysis because you don't like the results for some **political** reason is bad. Stay away!